# Accounts import gone wrong -- is it possible to roll back?

Tags: data-import-wizard

I imported some accounts into SF, but some of the fields weren't populated properly. Is there a way to roll back to the point before the data import? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an import is done, all transactions are final, so there's no going back. You have a few choices, possibly. If you have a Full Copy Sandbox, the old data might be in there. If you exported a report, edited it, then imported, the original exported report, if you still have it, could be imported to undo most mistakes. Aside from that, there's not much you can do about it now unless you have a backup. In the future, I recommend using, at minimum, the Weekly Data Export feature found in Setup, building a backup solution to help avoid accidents like this, purchasing Backup & Restore from salesforce.com directly, or checking the AppExchange for other backup solutions that suit your needs and budget. Much like any other kind of technology, you definitely should not be going without a backup of your Salesforce data, just in case something like this happens.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, that's good to know. Luckily I imported data into the sandbox. :)